# .NET MAUI rebinding not working when invoked via timer

Tags: c#, .net, frontend, client, maui

My API process payments externally and will provide certain data based on the result of the payment and so, as this happens outside of the client, the page doesn't know when to refresh or pull in the new records.

I wanted to use a timer, that automatically refreshes every 5 minutes by rebinding the ViewModel. I do this when a user signs out after everything is removed from memory and it works perfectly fine, however, when I do it via a timer the page appears blank and no information is displayed.

```
using Acre.ViewModels;

namespace Acre.Views
{
    public partial class PortfolioPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PortfolioPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new PortfolioViewModel();

            StartTimer();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "ReloadPortfolioUI", (sender) =>
            {
                RebindPage(); //works here
            });
        }

        public void StartTimer()
        {
            IDispatcherTimer timer4Registration;
            timer4Registration = Application.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
            timer4Registration.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            timer4Registration.Tick += (sender, e) => RebindPage(); //does not work here
            timer4Registration.Start();
        }

        public void RebindPage()
        {
            this.BindingContext = new PortfolioViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is `RebindPage` actually getting called by the timer?  Why are you creating a new instance of the VM each time?  This seems wasteful.  Seeing the code for the VM would be helpful

Comment: Could you please post the code of `YourPage.xaml` and `PortfolioViewModel.cs`?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of all this? Can't you ask your API if it has finished processing the payment? Or can't you use a pub/sub implementation? What you're doing here seems very inefficient (and wasteful as Jason already mentioned).